# Prove that two matrices have the same eigenvalues but one is non-diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm studying the module Algebra, and was reading the course book "Álgebra. Aplicaciones a Teoría de Códigos". I got stuck on this problem because I couldn't prove that a matrix is non-diagonalizable.

**Question:** Prove that the matrices $M_A$ and $M_B$ have the same eigenvalues but one is diagonalizable and the other is not. Diagonalize the one that is.

**My attempt:**

$M_A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$M_B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Both matrices have determinants equal to $1$, therefore, it will be necessary to prove it by their characteristic polynomial and calculating their eigenvalues:

The eigenvectors of $M_A$ are obtained with: $f_A(\lambda)=det(M_A-\lambda I_3)=0$, which means: $f(\lambda)=(-\lambda-1) \lambda^2+\lambda+1 = -\lambda^3-\lambda^2+\lambda+1 = 0 \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
\lambda_1 = 1 \rightarrow m_1 = 1\\
\lambda_2 = -1 \rightarrow m_{-1} = 2
\end{array} \right.$

The eigenvectors of $M_B$ are obtained with: $f_B(\lambda)=det(M_B-\lambda I_3)=0$, which means: $f(\lambda)=-(-\lambda-2)(1-\lambda)\lambda-\lambda+1 = -\lambda^3-\lambda^2+\lambda+1 = 0 \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
\lambda_1 = 1 \rightarrow m_1 = 1\\
\lambda_2 = -1 \rightarrow m_{-1} = 2
\end{array} \right.$

We obtain accordingly that they do not differ in eigenvalues, but it has not been shown that one is not diagonalizable. To prove it, we have to prove that $\nexists(C \land C^{-1}) \mid M_i=CD_iC^{-1}, \forall i \in \left\{ A,B \right\}$.

To prove it, we will first introduce the matrices $D_i, \forall i \in \left\{ A,B \right\}$

$D_A=D_B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, we will try to find the matrices $C^i_j, \forall i \in\left\{-1,1 \right\} \land \forall j \in\left\{A,B \right\}$

We know that a standard equation is: $M_i=C_iD_iC_i^{-1}, \forall i \in \left\{ A,B \right\}$

$M_i=C_iD_iC_i^{-1}$

$M_iC_i=C_iD_iC_i^{-1}C_i$

$M_iC_i=C_iD_iI_3$

$M_iC_iD^{-1}_i=C_iD_iD^{-1}_i$

$M_iC_iD^{-1}_i=C_iI_3$

$M_iC_iD^{-1}_i=C_i$

$C_i=M_iC_iD^{-1}_i$

We realize that to diagonalize a matrix, it is necessary that its inverse exists, that is: $D_i^{-1}$.

However $D_A=D_B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$, so both matrices $M_A$ and $M_B$ should be diagonalizable. This means that the non-diagonalization that any matrix could have has not yet been demonstrated.

We will now try to prove it by obtaining the associated subspaces:

$S_{A_{\lambda=1}}=\begin{pmatrix}
0-1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -1-1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0-1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow rg(S_{A_{\lambda=1}})= 2$

$S_{A_{\lambda=-1}}=\begin{pmatrix}
0-(-1) & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -1-(-1) & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0-(-1)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow rg(S_{A_{\lambda=-1}})= 1$

$S_{B_{\lambda=1}}=\begin{pmatrix}
0-1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -2-1 & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 1-1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -3 & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow rg(S_{B_{\lambda=1}})= 2$

$S_{B_{\lambda=-1}}=\begin{pmatrix}
0-(-1) & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -2-(-1) & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 1-(-1)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow rg(S_{B_{\lambda=-1}})= 2 $

In addition, the ranks of $M_A$ and $M_B$ are:

$rg(M_A)=3$

$rg(M_B)=3$

Therefore, since $[\cdots]$ $M_A$ is not possible to diagonalize but $M_B$ is.

Comment: hint: try squaring each matrix.  If a matrix $M$ is diagonalizable and each eigenvalue is $\pm 1$ then $M^2=I$ (i.e. an involution).

Comment: @user8675309 You're right, if I square $M_A$ I get $I_3$, but if I square $M_B$ I don't. Does that mean $M_B$ is non-diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes. If $M_B = SDS^{-1}$ and $D^2=I$ then $M_B^2 = SIS^{-1} = I$ but this did not happen. On the other hand an involution is always diagonalizable so long as $\text{char }\mathbb F\neq 2$.  In fact neither of your matrices are diagonalizable in characteristic 2.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by characteristic 2?Are you referring to the fact that the maximum rank/dimension of the subspaces is 2?

Comment: Your post did not state the field $\mathbb F$ that you are working over.  At some point you will likely see a case where your field is $\mathbb F_2$, the field with two elements and $2=0$-- this kind of thing is rather relevant when studying Algebra or coding theory.

Comment: I think I understood you, if I'm not wrong I'm working over the body $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R^3}$, more precisely in $\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$. As there is only one projection, does that mean I'm working over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$? (For example, would $\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^4}$ be $\mathbb{F}_3$, as there are 3 elements in such field?)

Comment: There seems to be some linguistic issues here.  $\mathbb R^3$ is a vector space not a field and I don't know what 'the body $\mathbb K$' means. Evidently your field is $\mathbb R$.  If you look up the definition of a vector space, it explicitly requires a field to be stated-- however many projections you identify as linear transformations for the vector space doesn't change the field. These kinds of details will become more important as you progress in algebra.

Comment: You're right, I meant to say the field $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ (In Spanish we use the letter K instead of F). My question is, if my vector space is $\mathbb{R}^3$, what characteristic are we in? I'm understanding that, for example, a vector space $\mathbb{F}_3$ is in characteristic 3 as it has 3 elements. However, does a vector space like $\mathbb{R}^3$ have infinite elements? (In the order of $\Omega$) If this is the case, I don't comprehend what you meant by "In fact neither of your matrices are diagonalizable in characteristic $2$" [...]

Comment: [...] when we would theoretically be in characteristic $\Omega$ or $\infty$ (I don't know the precise nomenclature). Or were you simply stating the fact that in $\mathbb{F}_2$ they are non-diagonalizable, but diagonzaliable $\forall \ \text{char}(\mathbb{F}) \neq 2$?

Comment: My point was you are working over a vector space but never declared the field.  If $V= \mathbb R^3$ then you are tacitly using $\mathbb R$ for your field.  If instead  $V= \mathbb K^3$ where $\mathbb K$ is any field of characteristic 2, then neither matrix would be diagonalizable.  I suspect you'll find that symbols $\mathbb K$ and $\mathbb F$ are both used when you study field theory more (e.g. in field extensions); your algebra book should (eventually) address your remaining questions in some detail.

Comment: The conclusion should be: "$M_A$ is diagonalizable, $M_B$ is not. This is because the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ of $M_A$ is 2-dimensional, while for $M_B$ only $1-dimesional."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working out the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalue -1. As in, what's the dimension of the space of eigenvectors for the eigenvalue -1?

For the diagonalizable matrix, the geometric multiplicity will be 2.

For the non-diagonalizable matrix, the geometric multiplicity will be 1. Upon calculating this you know the matrix is non-diagonalizable, because diagonalizability is equivalent to there being a basis of eigenvectors (for 3 dimensional space).

Basically, compute all the eigenvectors.

Comment: But isn't the geometric multiplicity 3 for both? I tried to demonstrate this here:

The eigenvectors of $M_A$ are: $\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
\lambda_1 = 1 \rightarrow m_1 = 1\\
\lambda_2 = -1 \rightarrow m_{-1} = 2
\end{array} \right.$ and the eigenvectors of $M_B$ are: $\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
\lambda_1 = 1 \rightarrow m_1 = 1\\
\lambda_2 = -1 \rightarrow m_{-1} = 2
\end{array} \right.$